# CloudKit CKSubscription Notification Basics

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, cloudkit

I have been fiddling about with `CKSubscription` today. I have a few queries regarding it.

I setup my subscription like so:

```
-(void)addSubscriptions
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];

    CKSubscription *newRecordSub = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:_recordTypeName predicate:predicate options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion];

    CKNotificationInfo *noteInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
    noteInfo.alertBody = @"Update!";
    noteInfo.shouldBadge = YES;
    noteInfo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    newRecordSub.notificationInfo = noteInfo;

    CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [container privateCloudDatabase];

    [privateDatabase saveSubscription:newRecordSub completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

**QUESTION 1:**

When creating my subscription, surely I only need to save this to my container once only? As this is called overtime the app runs, I get an error simply saying, duplicate subscription, so the app works as expected, but should I be approaching this differently and not running every time?

Next I setup to receive notifications with my `AppID` and registered for them in my `AppDelegate`.

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Lastly, I handle these notification as below:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    CKNotification *note = [CKNotification notificationFromRemoteNotificationDictionary:userInfo];

    if (note.notificationType == CKNotificationTypeQuery)
    {
        CKQueryNotification *queryNote = (CKQueryNotification *)note;
        CKRecordID *recordID = [queryNote recordID];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kCloudKitNewRecordFlightLog object:recordID];
    }
}
```

**QUESTION 2:**

Why would I not be receiving any notifications at this point? All my code runs and my app is updated when new records are added/deleted, updated. However, no sound, badge or banner is displayed to notify the user.

**QUESTION 3:**

Is it a sensible approach to when receiving the cloud kit notification to then have a local notification send a message to the relevant view to update the records?

Comment: you should create a stack overflow question for each question.

Comment: Will do in future, sorry! Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you only need to set them once. You could query the subscriptions (using fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler) to see if you should create it. Or just ignore the error.
2. That could work, or you could setup a delegate meganism.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. It is interesting you say subscriptions are public database only. I have this subscription working on my private database as shown, the only thing being is that it doesn't display notification, despite working in the background still.

Comment: That's strange. With subscriptions you should only receive notifications if the changes were made by someone other than the one that made the subscription. In the private database you will be the only one that will access the data. So you are saying that you do receive a notification events in your app? i have to admit I never tried subscriptions on the private database. I assumed it would not work.

Comment: Well it works at a basic level, it won't provide any banner, badge, sound etc. For example, using the code in my question, I can make a change on my iPhone and my iPad will receive that notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. I wasn't aware that they would normally be public only.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer why do you say subscriptions should only work with the public database? Subscriptions can be used to notify the user's other devices that one of the devices made a change in a private database.